# Remove querystring parameters from url with regex

Tags: javascript, jquery, regex

I'm pretty new to regex and need to remove some content from our url

```
 http://mysite.blah/problem/smtp/smtp-open-relay?page=prob_detail&showlogin=1&action=smtp:134.184.90.18
```

I need to remove everything from the "?" and on, leaving me just:

```
http://mysite.blah/problem/smtp/smtp-open-relay
```

Here is our current regex expression we are using to grab the route data. For example I can grab "smtp" and "smtp-open-relay" (which we need). However sometimes our url changes depending on where the user is coming from thereby appending the querystring parameters which is causing our current regex expression to blow up.

```
// Retrieve the route data from the route
var routeData = /([0-9a-zA-Z_.-]+)\/([0-9a-zA-Z_.-]+)$/g.exec(route);
```

I need it to ignore stuff from the "?" on.

Comment: you might try splitting on the ?.

Comment: It's really easy to get rid of the query string. Just do this: `url = url.split('?')[0]`

Answer (score 23, accepted):

A regular expression is probably more than you need.

You could do the following to remove the `?` and everything (query
string + hash) after it:

```
var routeData = route.split("?")[0];
```

If you truly wanted to strip only the query string, you could preserve
the hash by reconstructing the URL from the `window.location` object:

```
var routeData = window.location.origin + window.location.pathname + window.location.hash;
```

If you want the query string, you can read it with `window.location.search`.

Comment: I went with this solution. Thanks everyone for the help!

Answer (score 5):

i just used this one

```
    var routeData= route.substring(0, route.indexOf('?'));
```

Comment: What if index of is -1?

Comment: well routeData is ´undefined´ then

Answer (score 5):

Use this function:

```js
var getCleanUrl = function(url) {
  return url.replace(/#.*$/, '').replace(/\?.*$/, '');
};

// get rid of hash and params
console.log(getCleanUrl('https://sidanmor.com/?firstname=idan&lastname=mor'));
```

Answer (score 0):

If you're doing this in-browser, let the browser do the parsing:

```
location.origin + location.pathname
```

Or for arbitrary URLs:

```
function withoutQS(_url) {
    var url = document.createElement('a');
    url.href = _url;
    return url.origin + url.pathname;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Following is the cleaner way to remove a given parameter say: prop1 form querystring of url.
Querystring can be found in url by accessing

> window.location.search

Here you apply regular expression for prop1:

> var queryStringWithoutProp1=window.location.search.replace(/(&?prop1=)(.[^&]*)/,"");

queryStringWithoutProp1 must return querystring without prop1=value parameter-value combination from querystring

**Note:** '&?' ensures whether prop1 appears as first parameter or any subsequent one.